# Change the URL of an image from wp_get_attachment_image_src except in the frontpage

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, images

This is the code I used that is working, but I want it to work only on product posts and not on the frontpage.

```
function alterImageSRC($image, $attachment_id, $size, $icon){        
$image[0] = 'http://newimagesrc.com/myimage.jpg';

return $image;
}
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_src', 'alterImageSRC', 10, 4);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code worked for me:

```
function alterImageSRC($image, $attachment_id, $size, $icon){
        
    if ( is_front_page() ) {

    return $image;

        }

    $image[0] = 'http://newimagesrc.com/myimage.jpg';
    return $image;

    }

add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_src', 'alterImageSRC', 10, 4);
```